# How would I find the index of the smallest value in an int array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm fairly new to java so I would like to keep it simple, and I figure I would have to take the first value of the array then compare it to each following value and if the value is larger smaller than the first, replace the value with it, but I don't know how to get index from that.

Comment: Save the index along with the min value

Comment: If you want to keep it simple... there are tons of built-in sorting methods in the Arrays class... just sort the array then the index will be 0. Note... it's probably not the most "efficient solution" in terms of running time... but, it will work

Answer (score 5):

For an unstructured, unsorted array the best you can do, assuming you are only going to find the minimum value once, is a simple iteration over all elements (*O(n)* complexity), like so:

```
public int findMinIdx(int[] numbers) {
    if (numbers == null || numbers.length == 0) return -1; // Saves time for empty array
    // As pointed out by ZouZou, you can save an iteration by assuming the first index is the smallest
    int minVal = numbers[0] // Keeps a running count of the smallest value so far
    int minIdx = 0; // Will store the index of minVal
    for(int idx=1; idx<numbers.length; idx++) {
        if(numbers[idx] < minVal) {
            minVal = numbers[idx];
            minIdx = idx;
        }
    }
    return minIdx;
}
```

Also, in the case of a tie for minimum value, this method will return the index of the *first* case of that value it found. If you want it to be the *last* case, simply change `numbers[idx] < minVal` to `numbers[idx] <= minVal`.

Comment: This will not compile. 1. There's not method `size()` on array 2. You need to increment `idx` in the loop (not `i`). 3. You need to initialize `minIdx` since it's a local variable. You can save one iteration by setting the `minVal` to `numbers[0]` and `minIdx` to 0.

Comment: Whopse, been working with lists too much lately, absolutely correct.

Comment: @ZouZou then it will fail on empty arrays ;-)

Comment: Though actually, it will fail on empty arrays anyway right now (it will return zero rather than something else). I'll fix that.

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard Right. You can check if the array is `null` and the length property and return -1 directly :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is with Java 8

```
 public static int findMinIdx(int[] numbers) {
        OptionalInt minimun = IntStream.of(numbers).min();
        return   IntStream.of(numbers).boxed().collect(toList()).indexOf(minimun.getAsInt());
    }
```

Comment: in your code there is a typo . Please add  Collectors.toList()  instead of a naked toList()

Answer (score 0):

Never cared about run time optimization, was just looking for a solution!, this worked and this would help you too, finding the index of the lowest values in an array.

```
    // array[] -> Received the array in question as an parameter
    // index -> stores the index of the lowest value
    // in for loop, i is important to complete all the comparison in the function
    // When it finds a lower value between the two, it does not change the index
    // When it finds a lower value it changes it's index to that index
    // If array has same value more than once, it will provide index to that values last occurrence
    // Correct me if you find anything not working in this example...
    //...

private static int index_of_minimum_value(int[] array) {
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if ((array[i - 1] < array[i]) && ([index] > array[i - 1])) index = i - 1;
        else if (array[index] > array[i]) index = i;
    }
    return index;
}
```